# Get response time excluding prepared time in rest assured

Tags: rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, jira-rest-java-api

this screenshot is from Postman tool while hovering over **Time** after get request, is there any way to get time which is highlighted in red (**excluding prepare time**) as **Rest assured** is giving the yellow highlighted time(**including prepare time**).[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB19t.png)

i tried to use getTime() but that is not expected one which i need

Comment: Perhaps review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please post a sample snippet code how did u try.

Generally u can get the response time like below :

```
    Response response = RestAssured.get("url/endpoint");
    long responseTime = response.time();
    System.out.println("Response Time: " + responseTime + " milliseconds");
```

The above time will include below things:

**Request Sending Time:** The time taken to send the request to the server.

**Server Processing Time:** The time taken by the server to process the request.

**Response Receiving Time:** The time taken to receive the response from the server.

Comment: Is there any way, to get these 3 different times values separately?